# SQL mariaDB constraint fail

Tags: sql, constraints, mariadb

So i have two tables:

[image]

and

[image]

My goal is that when group row is deleted - it would automatically delete all files associated with that group. So i tried to add constraint like this:

[image]

However, i get such error:

[image]

Comment: `id` is not a foreign key I think. `group_id` is. Your constraint is not correctly defined. Switch `id` and `group_id` in your constraint.

Comment: im am setting it up in groups table, should i do it on files instead?

Comment: I think what you want is a trigger, not a constraint. A constraint is meant to display an error when a condition is not met. A trigger is executed when a condition is met. You want a trigger that executes on a delete in the group table, and that trigger deletes all files associated with that group in the files table.